# How do I factorise an infinite binomial expansion with negative index

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, factoring, binomial-theorem

So, I was wondering how could I factorise an infinite binomial expansion, say,

$$(1-2x)^{-1} = 1 + 2 x + 4 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 16 x^4 + \dots$$

I know that there exist methods to factorise infinite expansions but I couldn't find anything for the infinite binomial expansions with negative indices. So, how do we even proceed with this and get from the RHS to LHS since the existing methods depend on finding roots but the original term does not have any roots so is it even right to call it factorisation.
I would be really grateful if somebody could shed some light on how to factorise the polynomial or if it is even feasible or not.

Edit: What I wish to know that if we are given say 6 or 7 terms of an infinite binomial expansion and told that it is a binomial expansion then is there a general method with which we can arrive at the original binomial from that and that is what I meant by factorisation.

Say, $$f(x) = 1 + ax + bx^2 + cx^3 +...$$
is given to us and we are told that it is an infinite binomial expansion. Then, can we arrive at the original binomial which has a negative index.

Comment: This is not a factorization , it is an expansion.

Comment: Are you familiar with the geometric series? For $x<0.5$ this is exactly the connection from RHS to LHS.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: Also posted to, but closed on, MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457141/how-do-i-factorise-an-infinite-binomial-expansion-with-negative-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure What exactly do you mean by factorization, If you want to know a method to convert R.H.S form  into L.H.S form, Here is one of the methods

Let $$S= 1 + 2 x + 4 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 16 x^4 + \dots$$

$$Sx= x + 2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 8 x^4 + 16 x^5 + \dots$$
still the terms don't cancel out, so multiply $Sx$ by 2

$$2Sx=  2 x + 4 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 16 x^4 + \dots$$
now

$$S= 1 + 2 x + 4 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 16 x^4 + \dots     (1)$$
$$2Sx=  2 x + 4 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 16 x^4 + \dots   (2)$$
subtract (2) from (1)

$$(S-2Sx)=1$$

$$S(1-2x)=1$$
Hence
$$S=\frac{1}{1-2x}$$

which is

$$S=(1-2x)^{-1}$$

**Clarification to OP's Further doubts**

Let's define $\binom{n}{r}$ as $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)....(n-r+1)}{r(r-1)(r-2)....(3)(2)(1)}$ for simplicity

Consider general Binomial expansion

$(1+kx)^n$, Where $k,x,n$ are real number

$(1+kx)^n=\binom{n}{0}(kx)^0+\binom{n}{1}(kx)^1+\binom{n}{2}(kx)^2+\binom{n}{3}(kx)^3+\binom{n}{4}(kx)^4.........$

Now according to OP, It is given that

$f(x)=1+ax+bx^2+cx^3......\tag3$ is indeed a binomial expansion, Which means

$f(x)=\binom{n}{0}(kx)^0+\binom{n}{1}(kx)^1+\binom{n}{2}(kx)^2+\binom{n}{3}(kx)^3+\binom{n}{4}(kx)^4........\tag 4$

Now OP wants to go Backwards i. e from f(x) to Binomial expansion, as it is not always so obvious to identify the coefficients if f(x) is practically given as expanded form of binomial expansion

$f(x)=1+ax+bx^2+cx^3......$

Comparing (3) and (4)

$$k=\frac{coefficient(x)}{\binom{n}{1}}=\frac{coefficient(x)}{n}=\frac{a}{n}$$

$$b=coefficient(x^2)=\frac{k^2(n)(n-1)}{2}$$

$$k^2=\frac{2b}{n(n-1)}$$

solving for $n,k$

$$n=\frac{a^2}{a^2-2b}$$
$$k=\frac{a^2-2b}{a}$$

After finding $k,n$,

One can always write $f(x)=(1+kx)^n$

Applying above on

$$f(x)= 1 + 2 x + 4 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 16 x^4 + \dots$$
$$a=2,b=4$$
it follows

$$k=-2,n=-1$$

$$f(x)=(1+kx)^n=(1-2x)^{-1}$$

**Clarification to OP's More interesting doubts**

You can Always find All terms using differentiation, Everything we did above can also be analysed by differentiation, Only if it is given that the series is indeed a binomial expansion or product of 2 or more binomial expansions

Let's apply this technique to $$f(x)=1+cx+dx^2+ex^3......=(1+Ax^a)\cdot (1+Bx^b)^q$$

If it is given that the series is indeed a product of two or more binomial expansion

We can Write

$$(1+Ax^a)\cdot (1+Bx^b)^q=1+cx+dx^2+ex^3......$$

Differentiate it one by one and always put $x=0$, Here variables are $A,B,p,q,a,b$

Hence you will need to differentiate 6 times and put $x=0$ again and again to obtain 6 equations, These 6 equations ,when solved will give you Your desired reduced form

If you apply this to $$(1+kx)^n=1+2x+4x^2+8x^3........$$

Differentiate once

$$nk(1+kx)^{n-1}=2+8x+24x^2.......$$

Put $x=0$

$$nk=2\tag 1$$

Differentiate again

$$n(n-1)k^2(1+kx)^{n-2}=8+48x+.....$$

Put $x=0$

$$n(n-1)k^2=8 \tag 2$$

Solving equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives you $n=-1$ and $k=-2$

Such things can be done for any number of products of binomial expansion, But with every product the equations of variable formed gets more complex, Also it must be given that $f(x)$ is indeed product of two or more binomial expansions

Comment: Yes, this is what i wished to know but I wanted to know a general method. The method you have provided may not work for all such expansion such as if the power were to be changed to -2. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: even in the new question, essentially, are you just asking how to prove binomial expansion of $(1+kx)^n$ for negative integers from R.H.S form to L.H.S form , instead to general L.H.S Form to R.H.S form?

Comment: Not a proof but  a method of factorisation. Like, if I was given the  expansion of the original binomial but to the power of -2, then how do i arrive at the binomial.

Comment: @Poke_Programmer,Not every polynomial as you wrote $f(x)$ can be factorised as a to a term raised to a power

Comment: I'm not referring to every polynomial but the expansion of a binomial if it seemed that I was or are you saying that for the binomial case that i have given. If you are then can you please give just a bit of further reasoning no matter how trivial as I have not come across anything of the sort in my investigation. Even a link for further study would suffice. Thanks!

Comment: @Poke_Programmer,Edited to clarify

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you further tell me the suitability of the term factorisation for this that is getting the binomial term from the expansion.

Comment: @Poke_Programmer,What do you mean to ask? What is suitability?

Comment: I meant that if I wish to talk with someone about converting the expansion to the binomial then telling them that I wish to factorize the expansion is mathematically correct or incorrect. If it is incorrect then please suggest some term that would help the other person understand what I wish to convey.

Comment: @Poke_Programmer, You can use  words like  "Reduced form" or maybe "how to write following series in collapsed form" etc. There are many ways to tell what you want to convey, This is not a mathematical problem to be correct or incorrect, Rather , it is a Linguistic choice

Comment: I understand. I just had one final question which is if it is possible to do so for expansions formed by product of two such binomials, say,                                          
$$ f(x) = (1-Ax)^{-p}*(1-Bx)^{-q }= 1+ax+bx^2+cx^3......$$

Comment: Do you mean to ask a more generalised version like $$f(x)=(1+Ax^a)^p \cdot (1+Bx^b)^q?$$

Comment: Yes, just like the previous one if we are given the expansion can we arrive at the original two binomials, that is, obtained the reduced form.

Comment: @Poke_Programmer, Edited to clarify